# My code is not being pushed to the GIT, committed. But it's loading without any results

Tags: r, git, github, version-control, rstudio

I'm learning `RStudio`, and I'm stuck with my code not being able to be pushed to the GIT. To give you a brief, I was using another account for the GIT and I used to clone a team repo through it. Recently, I have made my personal account on GIT and have started to work on it. Initially, when I tried to push the code, it was pushing to the previous team repo and my personal account isn't a collaborator of that. It sent an error as  **`unable to access 'https://github.com/AyushSaxena0402/Testing.git/': The requested URL returned an error: 403`**

After going through some solutions, I deleted my previous account on my Windows system. Now when I try to push the code, it doesn't show this message instead the progress bar keeps loading and doesn't give any result too. I'm pretty new to coding, hence it's pretty hard to understand other answers. If someone can help me out, it'll be great.

Attaching the screenshot of the progress bar. [Screenshot of the loading progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpdBG.png)

Comment: try checking if your current git config is as expected. From a terminal (there is a terminal pane in Rstudio, or via `git bash` etc)  first make sure you are located in your git repository and then run `git config --list`. It will return your name, e-mail, remote url, and some more info. If there are any inconsistencies, then `git config --local user.mail "your@mail"`, and `git config --local user.name "Your Name" to reset these configs.

Comment: @MarceloAvila I have checked what you mentioned, everything seems to be fine. I don't find any errors in it. Any other suggestions which I could do to fix this?

Comment: I don't know... you can try running the git commands straight in terminal (git commit, git push, and see you get some info with the error)

Comment: Are you on Windows, and did you recently update Git to version 2.32? If so, you have hit a Windows-specific bug that is new in Git 2.32. Downgrade to 2.30, or switch to ssh, to get around the bug.

Comment: I have sorted the issue. I opened the PowerShell through my located local folder. And I tried to push the file through it. I figured out that my local file was not connected to the GITHUB account (Needed authentication). After I provided my username and password, the files are now being pushed to the GITHUB repo. Thank you guys for the effort in solving the issue.